# Proving that two expressions with different variables are logically equivalent.

Tags: logic

For example, prove that if A AND B and A AND C are logically equivalent.
How would I go doing this? I thought of using two truth tables:

```
A | B | A AND B
T   T      T
T   F      F
F   T      T
F   F      T

A | C | A AND C
T   T      T
T   F      F
F   T      T
F   F      T
```

Then concluding they are logically equivalent. However, they are from two seperate truth tables. Would that be correct? Or do I have to combine the truth tables?

Comment: You got some of your Ts and Fs mixed up. The tables you show are for $A \lor B$ and $A \lor C$. In order to test logical equivalence you would need to combine truth tables and add four rows to account for the fact that you have another propositional variable to deal with.

Comment: Once you have constructed a single truth table as in Paul's first one below, then either verify that the two columns corresponding to your two sentences match in every row, _or_ add a final column $\text“(A∧B)↔(A∧C)"$ then verify that it contains `T` in every row. Remember, 'logical equivalent' means that whatever meaning is assigned to the variables the two sentences share a truth value.

Answer (score 2):

As PW_246 says, you need a combined truth table involving all variables, not separate truth tables for each expression. Using the actual truth table for $A \wedge B$, we get
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
A&B&C&A\wedge B&A\wedge C\\\hline
T&T&T&T&T\\
T&T&F&\color{red}T&\color{red}F\\
T&F&T&\color{red}F&\color{red}T\\
T&F&F&F&F\\
F&T&T&F&F\\
F&T&F&F&F\\
F&F&T&F&F\\
F&F&F&F&F
\end{array}$$

For an example where they are equivalent,
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
A&B&C&A\wedge (B\vee\lnot B)&A\wedge (C\vee\lnot C)\\\hline
T&T&T&T&T\\
T&T&F&T&T\\
T&F&T&T&T\\
T&F&F&T&T\\
F&T&T&F&F\\
F&T&F&F&F\\
F&F&T&F&F\\
F&F&F&F&F
\end{array}$$
which holds since $A\wedge (B\vee\lnot B)$ does not actually depend on the value of $B$ at all.

In general, that will be the case: two expressions involving different sets of variables will only be equivalent if they do not actually depend on the variables that differ between the sets (and of course, give the same values for the variables that are in both sets).